# How to join more than 2 regions with Apache Geode?

Tags: join, geode

I've been trying to query some regions and i'm failing to join more than 2 of them. I set that up in a Java test to run them more easily but it fails all the same in pulse.

```java
@Test
public void test_geode_join() throws QueryException {
    ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory()
        .addPoolLocator(HOST, LOCATOR_PORT)
        .setPoolSubscriptionEnabled(true)
        .setPdxSerializer(new MyReflectionBasedAutoSerializer())
        .create();

    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        SelectResults<StructImpl> r = (SelectResults<StructImpl>) cache.getQueryService()
            .newQuery("SELECT itm.itemId, bx.boxId " +
                "FROM /items itm, /boxs bx " +
                "WHERE itm.boxId = bx.boxId " +
                "LIMIT 5")
            .execute();

        for (StructImpl v : r) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }

    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        SelectResults<StructImpl> r = (SelectResults<StructImpl>) cache.getQueryService()
            .newQuery("SELECT bx.boxId, rm.roomId " +
                "FROM /boxs bx, /rooms rm " +
                "WHERE bx.roomId = rm.roomId " +
                "LIMIT 5")
            .execute();

        for (StructImpl v : r) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }

    {
        // That fails
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        SelectResults<StructImpl> r = (SelectResults<StructImpl>) cache.getQueryService()
            .newQuery("SELECT itm.itemId, bx.boxId, rm.roomId " +
                "FROM /items itm, /boxs bx, /rooms rm " +
                "WHERE itm.boxId = bx.boxId " +
                "AND bx.roomId = rm.roomId " +
                "LIMIT 5")
            .execute();

        for (StructImpl v : r) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
}
```

The first 2 queries work fine and respond in an instant but the last query holds until it timeouts. I get the following logs

```
[warn 2018/02/06 17:33:17.155 CET <main> tid=0x1] Pool unexpected socket timed out on client connection=Pooled Connection to hostname:31902: Connection[hostname:31902]@1978504976)

[warn 2018/02/06 17:33:27.333 CET <main> tid=0x1] Pool unexpected socket timed out on client connection=Pooled Connection to hostname2:31902: Connection[hostname2:31902]@1620459733 attempt=2)

[warn 2018/02/06 17:33:37.588 CET <main> tid=0x1] Pool unexpected socket timed out on client connection=Pooled Connection to hostname3:31902: Connection[hostname3:31902]@422409467 attempt=3)

[warn 2018/02/06 17:33:37.825 CET <main> tid=0x1] Pool unexpected socket timed out on client connection=Pooled Connection to hostname3:31902: Connection[hostname3:31902]@422409467 attempt=3). Server unreachable: could not connect after 3 attempts

[info 2018/02/06 17:33:37.840 CET <Distributed system shutdown hook> tid=0xd] VM is exiting - shutting down distributed system

[info 2018/02/06 17:33:37.840 CET <Distributed system shutdown hook> tid=0xd] GemFireCache[id = 1839168128; isClosing = true; isShutDownAll = false; created = Tue Feb 06 17:33:05 CET 2018; server = false; copyOnRead = false; lockLease = 120; lockTimeout = 60]: Now closing.

[info 2018/02/06 17:33:37.887 CET <Distributed system shutdown hook> tid=0xd] Destroying connection pool DEFAULT
```

And it ends up crashing

```
org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerConnectivityException: Pool unexpected socket timed out on client connection=Pooled Connection to hostname3:31902: Connection[hostname3:31902]@422409467 attempt=3). Server unreachable: could not connect after 3 attempts
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.handleException(OpExecutorImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.handleException(OpExecutorImpl.java:623)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.execute(OpExecutorImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.execute(OpExecutorImpl.java:115)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.PoolImpl.execute(PoolImpl.java:763)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.QueryOp.execute(QueryOp.java:58)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ServerProxy.query(ServerProxy.java:70)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.executeOnServer(DefaultQuery.java:456)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:338)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:319)
    at local.test.geode.GeodeTest.test_geode_join(GeodeTest.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

I tried to set timeouts at 60 seconds but i'm still not getting any results.

All regions are configured like this:

```
 Type  |      Name       | Value
------ | --------------- | --------------------
Region | data-policy     | PERSISTENT_REPLICATE
       | disk-store-name | regionDiskStore1
       | size            | 1173
       | scope           | distributed-ack
```

Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the information provided, it looks like you are doing everything correct.  I tried to reproduce in a simple test (similar test) and the test returns 5 results.  However, if one of the predicates did not match, it could cause the query to take a lot longer to join enough rows to find a tuple that matches.

Below is a sample test that does not have an issue, but if I modify the test to put into region3 only portfolios with ID = -1.  Then the test "hangs" trying to find 5 rows that fulfill the search criteria (it has to join `1000 * 1000 * 1000` rows which takes awhile to do).  In the end the query will not find an `p3.ID = p1.ID`.  Is it possible that the `itm.boxIds` just do not match `box.boxId` often enough so it takes a lot longer to find ones that do?

```
public void testJoinMultipleReplicatePersistentRegionsWithLimitClause() throws Exception {

String regionName = "portfolio";
Cache cache = serverStarterRule.getCache();
assertNotNull(cache);
Region region1 =
    cache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.REPLICATE_PERSISTENT).create(regionName + 1);
Region region2 =
    cache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.REPLICATE_PERSISTENT).create(regionName + 2);
Region region3 =
    cache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.REPLICATE_PERSISTENT).create(regionName + 3);

for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  Portfolio p = new Portfolio(i);
  region1.put(i, p);
  region2.put(i, p);
  region3.put(i, p);  //modify this line to region3.put(i, new Portfolio(-1)) to cause query to take longer
}

QueryService queryService = cache.getQueryService();

SelectResults results = (SelectResults) queryService
    .newQuery("select p1.ID, p2.ID, p3.ID from /portfolio1 p1, /portfolio2 p2, /portfolio3 p3 where p1.ID = p2.ID and p3.ID = p1.ID limit 5").execute();

assertEquals(5, results.size());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you add how you create serverStarterRule to it ? I'm trying to do more testing but i'm getting some erratic behaviors. Also what method do you use to register a proper serializer for Portfolio ?

Comment: Actually, I seem to have fixed my issues by adding proper indexs. It also seems that the random issues i had were due to tests not cleaning up the local state after each run thus the changes I was making weren't always taken into account